# "Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization." - but it has no effect

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, desktop-bridge

When adding an **app.manifest** file to a .Net 6.0 WPF application, the **app.manifest** file contains the following commented:

> Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and
> registry virtualization.  Remove this element if your application
> requires this virtualization for backwards compatibility.

followed by the following (not commented):

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

However, whether the `requestedExecutionLevel` is or is not commented has no effect. I tried both as a simple WPF application, and also with a **Windows Application Packaging Project**. After running the following:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\test.txt";
File.Create(path);
```

and then opening **C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local**.

In a regular WPF project, **test.txt** *always* exists.

In a packaged project, it *always* doesn't.

So does `requestedExecutionLevel` have any effect? If so, when?

Comment: @HansPassant According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#appdata-operations-on-windows-10-version-1903-and-later) the file should appear in appdata even in a packaged app. But it doesn't. (My Windows version is 19045.2130)

Comment: These are distinct features.  requestedExecutionLevel and the comment applies only to UAC virtualization, the kind of feature that was important at Vista time when programs commonly wrote files to protect file system directories.  AppData is not protected so a WPF app has no trouble writing it.  The link refers to APPX manifested apps, Win10 acquired virtualization to AppData files to ensure that uninstalling the app doesn't leave files behind.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. That clears that up. You can change your comment into an answer because it seems to be the answer to my question.